# Model first approach, default value of property is not generated in the SQL script

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I have a model, developed with Entity Framework 6. I have defined default values for some properties (e.g., `True` for Property `A` of type `Boolean`). When I generate my Database from Model, the default values are not generated in the script. Is there any way for generating them?

Comment: does the column get created as a boolean or bit in the database?

Comment: @terribletp The column is created as bit

Comment: well if it was code first, I'd tell you to set it to true in the constructor.  I don't know if modifying the constructor is on the table for you.

Comment: @terribletp actually no, because the code is generated automatically from the model. The Property _is_ set in the cunstructor, but I want it to be set also automatically in the database (or better to say, in the script, with which I generate the database tables).